# I deleted images in my Openshift Wordpress app but they still show up

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, git, openshift

I'm running a MySQL 5.1, PHP 5.3, phpMyAdmin 4.0 application on Openshift and installed Wordpress over it.

I have a header image that rotates through a random set of images in a folder. I had some test images to start, but now I've deleted them and replaced them with production images.

The issue stems when I still see the test images rotate through on my page even though I deleted from my folder and git-pushed. I also ran **git add -u**, and tried **git rm** but didn't remember the filepath of the test images. I've cleared my browser cache.

How can I track down and actually delete these test images?

-self-admitting dev noob

Answer (score 0):

I tested locally and couldn't resolve the error, so just created a new empty folder, added the prod assets and linked to there.